# WP ACF echoes variable even if not wanted

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have strange problem, i've done the same thing before, many times.
But for some reason this one field just dosent want to co-operate whatsoever...

```
            <?php if (have_rows('subfamilies_product_changes')) :

            while ( have_rows('subfamilies_product_changes') ) : the_row();

            $url = the_sub_field('subfamilies_product_changes_link');

            echo    "<div class='support-lahko'>";
            echo        "<div class='support-logo'>";
            echo        the_date( 'Y-m-d' );
            echo        "</div>";
            echo        "<div class='news-name-product'>";
            echo        "<h3 style='vertical-align: middle;'>" . the_sub_field('subfamilies_product_changes_title') ."</h3>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo        "<div class='news-desc'>";
            echo        "</div>";
            echo    "</div>";
            echo "<br>";


            endwhile;
            endif;
```

It seems, no matter where i put my `<a>` tags, this script is just going to go ahead and for some reason echo the link from `$url = the_sub_field('subfamilies_product_changes_link');` into where ever it is defined. when i try to do something like `<a href=' . $url . '>` It will still just echo the url in `<p>` tags in seemingly random place.

Here is picture of what happens when i put `$url` inside href:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zcgS.jpg

href stays empty, and wp just echoes url where it was defined. none of the text in image is a link.

I would just need to echo the url INTO the href, so i can iterate links into pdf files.

```
the_sub_field('subfamilies_product_changes_title')
```

produces text: Test Changes, as expected.

Comment: You need to use get_sub_field()

Comment: ..... whelp, yeah. Thank you

Comment: No problems mate.

Comment: you can put that up as an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - use get_sub_field();

the_sub_field() outputs it immediately.

Glad that it helped - sometimes it is the smallest thing that ruins our day.